# Docker socket.io

Tags: docker, socket.io

I am trying to run the client from docker so that it connects to my server that is outside the containers but does not connect to me, it only works if I run it locally or if I pass the --netork host parameter, the latter is not valid since I have what to launch multiple containers

This is my code

```
var client = require('socket.io-client');
var options = {
    secure:true,
    reconnect: true,
    rejectUnauthorized : false,
    forceNew : true
    };
var socket = client.connect('wss://192.168.1.15:8443',options);

var channel = process.env.SESSION;
var canal_1 = channel+'-1';
var canal_2 = channel+'-2';

socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on(canal_1, function(data){
    
    console.log(data)
});
socket.on(canal_2, function(data){
    
    console.log(data)
});

socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

And this is my docker

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add --update alpine-sdk wget libxtst-dev libpng-dev python2 xorg-server-dev

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install robotjs

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "node"]
```

And this my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-socket",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs socket",
  "author": "Ricardo Jimenez Hurtado <jimenezhurtadoricardo@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "express",
    "socket"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my run code for docker

```
docker run -ti -e SESSION=1 node_server client_socket.js
```

Thanks for all

Best regards

Comment: Is your server application also running in a container?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want here in a number of ways.

The best of which would be to also run your server node in a docker container, and use docker networks to enable communication between the server and clients.

Comment: My application run in a container, in a swarm cluster, and many services run this application for wait the message send for the server

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with two steps, first I develop a better code with socket.io and socket.io-client for that the client join to a room and sendo step I revise all my network configuration for that my servername can be find for all my networks device

thanks for all